# Is there an unbounded countable set of ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Let $\text{Ord}=\{0,1,\ldots,\omega,\ldots\}$ be the set of ordinals. Does $\text{Ord}$ have an unbounded countable subset? In particular, is
$$\{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{\omega^\omega},...\}$$
unbounded?

Comment: There is no "*set* of (all) ordinals", and every *set* of ordinals is bounded.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3147034/473276) is relevant. In fact the class $\mathrm{Ord}$ does not have any unbounded subsets at all, of any cardinality! This is because you can take the supremum of any set of ordinals. The supremum of your set is an ordinal called $\epsilon_0$. You might also observe that $\omega_1$ is an upper bound (in fact very comfortably so).

Comment: Each of the ordinals in your sequence is countable, so any uncountable ordinal is an upper bound. The least upper bound is a countable ordinal called $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: @user14111 $\omega^\omega$ is countable? Isn't it llike $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$? What am I missing?

Comment: @AnneBauval Ok, then what would be the supremum of all ordinals?

Comment: Supremum in which ordered set???

Comment: I understood your $\omega^\omega$ etc. as *ordinal exponentiation*. If you meant *cardinal exponentiation* then of course $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ is an uncountable cardinal, and the least upper bound of your increasing sequence of cardinal numbers is a cardinal number called $\beth_\omega$.

Comment: @AnneBauval I see, $\text{Ord}$ is a class but not a set. Thus it does not have a supremum. But does there exist a countable unbounded *subclass* of $\text{Ord}$?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen $\epsilon_0$ and $\omega_1$ are different? And you say that the latter "comfortably" bounds my sequence. What would be a sequence whose supremum were $\omega_1$?

Comment: Even "if" this class $\text{Ord}$ were a set, its hypothetical supremum (in $\text{Ord}$ *itself*) would be the (obviously non-existing) largest ordinal. As for your question "*does there exist a countable unbounded subclass of Ord
?*": what does "countable class" mean, if not "countable set"? (and we already saw that every set of ordinals is bounded).

Comment: @AnneBauval countable class: a class in 1-to-1 correspondence with $\mathbb{N}$. I don't see the catch. Or is it that a countable class is a set?

Comment: Yes it is, provided your "correspondence" is definable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement).

Comment: Luca, I wonder what your education in set theory and pure maths is? I think it's great that you're interested in set theory and ordinals, but it seems that you have some confusions that would be addressed by any standard book or set of lecture notes on introductory set theory (and answerers here will likely assume you have some background understanding). If you're halfway through such a text I would recommend finishing it first - often questions and doubts will be answered if you just press on a bit. It's a famous result that there is no countable increasing sequence with supremum $\omega_1$.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen As far as my understanding goes, MSE is a Q&A math forum. If you don't feel like answering my question because there's no interest to you in solving ground-level doubts that are yet long past your set theory level, so be it. I respect that; I could even feel the same in your shoes. However, nowhere here does it require to carry a book worth of knowledge in mind before asking any questions. I'd even say that 95% of users break that rule. It's not the philosophy of this forum, unlike that of Math Overflow if I'm not mistaken. There you won't find any undergraduate level doubts...

Comment: I started "Set Theory" by C. C. Pinter but quit 3 chapters in for mental health reasons. However after your comment I'll come back to it for closure. Also, your questionning of my *pure* math knowledge is utterly unfounded. There's no need for condescence. Says my ego.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean to be rude or condescend but I realise my comment does look like that. It's absolutely true that you can ask whatever you want on MSE, but from your comments (eg not knowing that $\omega^\omega$ is countable), it seems to me that you lack some background understanding that a straightforward answer to your question would assume. In some sense it looks like you "don't know what you don't know". My point is a book is very valuable in that situation because it has had much more time and effort put into it and it always introduces concepts in an organised structured manner.

Comment: I especially apologise for asking about your pure maths background - that was rude. I asked because set theory disproportionately attracts people who do not otherwise have a university-level background in maths. I don't think there's anything wrong with that (in fact I think it's pretty cool!), but such people often have less experience of "how to learn maths", so the advice such a person would need is slightly different. My intention really is to help you resolve your doubts! I just think that me (or anyone) writing a single answer for you here probably won't help you as much as you think.

Comment: I totally agree with you. See, this question emerged somehow as I tackled a topology problem. I posted it here out of curiosity and wasn't expecting such a simple answer to debunk so many myths in my head. My follow up questions were led by a lazy urge to see how mislead I was, out of mere curiosity. Wasn't expecting to *learn* the subject. In that sense I must apologize for putting in less effort in my questions than you folks in your answers. Anyway, I'll take on that reading again.

Answer (score 0):

Your construction itself  almost constitutes a proof that the supremum of that set exists by transfinite induction.

- $F(0) = \omega$
- $F(a+1) = \omega^{F(a)}$
- $F(b) = \bigcup_{x<b} F(x)$ when $b$ is a limit ordinal.

The supremum of your set is $F(\omega)$

Comment: The supremum $F(\omega)$ has a name $\varepsilon_0$.